# What's the most efficient way to handle infinite tasks in Producer/Consumer?

Tags: c#, concurrency, producer-consumer

I have Gigabytes of data (stored in messages, each message is about 500KB) in a cloud queue (Azure) and data keeps coming.

I need to do some processing on each message. I've decided to create 2 background workers, one to get the data into memory, and the other to process that data:

```
GetMessage(CloudQueue cloudQueue, LocalQueue localQueue)
{
    lock (localQueue)
    {
        localQueue.Enqueue(cloudQueue.Dequeue());
    }
}

ProcessMessage(LocalQueue localQueue)
{
    lock (localQueue)
    {
        Process(localQueue.Dequeue());
    }
}
```

The issue is that data never stops coming so I'll be spending ALOT of time on synchronizing the local queue. Is there a known pattern for this type of problem?

Comment: Are you really convinced it *is* a problem? How much effort do you think is expended locking compared with the time taken to actually process the message? (There may well be simple lock-free approaches, but I see no evidence yet that the locking is actually signficant...)

Comment: @JonSkeet I ran VS analyzer and saw that it spends around 20% in locking (probably because the processing thread is starving)

Comment: What do you mean by "in locking" exactly? Within a lock, or actually performing locking? As djna has noted (and I didn't spot, stupidly) you're currently processing the queue message *within* the lock, which is a very bad idea... but that doesn't mean you're spending a lot of time on the actual synchronization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to hold the lock while you process

```
Item i;
lock (localQueue)
{
    i = localQueue.Dequeue();
}
Process(i);
```

Hence there should be little contention. If necessary, reduce the frequency with which the Producer takes the lock for enqueuing by batching the insertions: rather than the queue hold individual items have it hold batches. You effectively reduce the number of locks by a factor which is the average batch size. You can have a simple model of batching, say, every 10 or by time or some combination of time and threshold.